# Extract Telemetry Message Content and Respond With IOTCore Command to Device

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to GCloud and am looking for a way to extract telemetry messages sent by devices to IOTCore, and in response send an IOTCore command to the device based on the message content.

I have Pub/Sub Topics set up which receive the messages. For example, I have:

```
{temp1: 32}
{temp2: 27}
{temp3: 25}
```

sent from the device to IOTCore. I want to be able to read the value of each message and if it is above 30, send a command to the device:

```
{temp1: toohot}.
```

I've been researching for hours about cloud functions, dataflow, bigQuery, but I haven't found a clear way to do this. I don't mind which API is used, but the simpler the better.

If anyone has sample code, links or advice it'd be much appreciated.

Regards,

a12

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud IoT core documentation notes that registries for devices can be set up with a companion Cloud Pub/Sub [telemetry topic](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#creating_a_device_registry). Telemetry events can then be consumed from this topic by your application using a [Cloud Pub/Sub subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#core_concepts). After receiving an event, you can process it in your application and then [send a command to the device](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/commands) if needed.

There are multiple ways to write your application to process the events. You can do this by deploying a Cloud Function triggered by the topic as outlined in [the guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#functions_helloworld_pubsub_tutorial-go). If you would like to have a deployed server, you can [create a subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-subscription) and use it to receive messages in your application. Using a push subscription, you can receive events as requests to a server [running on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#run_pubsub_server-python) or [running on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages) or to an HTTPS endpoint. Alternatively, if you’d like control over the rate of receiving and processing events, you can choose to use a [pull subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull).